# batch and for each entry

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, wmic

We need a batch script to see what mappings are already active, delete the mapping and remapping the same once but with new password.

I have the following code example:

```
@echo off
set server=srv1

for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get Caption^, providername^| find /I "%server%"')  do ( 
    for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%d in ("%%a") do ( 
        echo net use %%a /del 
        for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%e in ("%%a", "%%b") do (
            echo net use %%a %%b /user:dom/uid1 pwd
        )
    )
)
```

The problem is that I need first to delete all mappings and after that to do all remappings.

My current code does: deleting, remapping, deleting, remapping.

Can some one help me with my code example?

Comment: you are pretty much running 3 loops which can be done with a single loop.

Comment: and how is it right?

Comment: give my answer below a try.

Comment: Please be specific here. Do you want to check for All mapped drives and remap them, or do you want to specify a single map and remap?

Comment: I would suggest you start by running the following command, `WMIC NetUse Get LocalName,RemoteName,UserName` That should hopefully give you the information you need to parse for your remapping. You could of course try to use it in a batch file `For` loop to save the information as variables. An untested example may be `('WMIC NetUse Where "RemotePath Like '\\\\srv1\\%%' And UserName='dom\\uid1'" Get LocalName^,RemotePath^|Find /V ""')`, but you may have to play with it to output what you need!

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you need to store the current mappings somwhow. I would do that in array-like environment variables, like `$MAP[1]`, `$MAP[2]`, for instance. Since the `Caption` attribute always seems to be a drive letter plus a colon, and the `ProviderName` attribute always seems to be a UNC path, a variable `$MAP[1]` could hold something like `<Caption>|<ProviderName>`.

So let us establish two separate loops, where the first one does the deletions and the data storage and the second one does the remapping activities -- like this, for example:

```cmd
@echo off
set "SERVER=srv1"

rem // Initialise index counter:
set /A "COUNT=0"
rem /* Capture output of the `wmic` command line that is filtered by a `where` clause;
rem    this returns only the drives, filtered for network drives (`DriveType=4`);
rem    two nested loops avoid text conversion artefacts like orphaned CR marks: */
for /F "delims=" %%K in ('
    wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=4 and ProviderName like '\\\\%SERVER%\\%%'" get DeviceID /VALUE
') do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("%%K") do (
    rem /* Capture output of the `wmic` command line that returns the mapping target
    rem    that corresponds with the current drive: */
    for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
        wmic LogicalDisk where "DeviceID='%%J'" get ProviderName /VALUE
    ') do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%E in ("%%G") do (
        rem // Increment index counter:
        set /A "COUNT+=1"
        rem // Revert handling of `&` by `wmic`, hence replace `&amp;` by `&`:
        set "NAME=%%F" & call set "NAME=%%NAME:&amp;=&%%"
        rem /* Store current mapping into array-like variable;
        rem    `call` and double-`%` in `%%COUNT%%` are necessary as `COUNT` is modified
        rem    and read within the same block of code (`%COUNT%` would return `0`): */
        call set "$MAP[%%COUNT%%]=%%J|%%NAME%%"
        rem // Delete the current mapping:
        ECHO net use %%J /DELETE
    )
)

rem // Loop over all array elements:
for /F "tokens=1-2* delims=|=" %%H in ('2^> nul set $MAP[') do (
    rem // Establish remapping with new user data:
    ECHO net use %%I "%%J" pwd /USER:dom/uid1
    rem // Delete handled array element:
    set "%%H="
)
```

Of course you need to set and adapt your filter variable `SERVER` first (used for `where` clause, which replaces your `find` command). I changed the search string to `\\%SERVER%\`, so full server names are matched only.

This approach handles network paths containing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> and ampersands (`&`) correctly.

To actually delete and remap the remote paths, remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands.

Comment: Thanks for down-voting without giving any reason!!

Comment: Forget about my post!! it was my fault!  The Code from aschipfl are working for 100%!
Thank you very much for your helping, every thing are working well. 
wrbrgds
AxelF

Comment: OK thank you very much for your deleting comments I try to do better next time.
One other question, what's happend if the directory path has a space in it like `\\srv1\shared folder`?
Many Thanks to all!

Comment: If spaces occur, like `\\srv1\shared folder`, the script uses `\\srv1\shared` only; tell me if you need to handle spaces too, then I'll update the script accordingly...

Comment: yes please, indeed we have one directory it hat a space in it.
I have tried to change the the code from `for /F "tokens=1,2"`to `for /F "tokens=1,2*"` and add `call set "$MAP[%%COUNT%%]=%%I|%%J"`to `call set "$MAP[%%COUNT%%]=%%I|%%J %%K"` that shows the full path but then i have quotation marks with space :-(

Comment: Finally the script is capable of handling paths with spaces and also `&` correctly. I believe the `"` with space you mentioned was caused by trailing spaces in the paths returned by the `wmic` query. Such can be avoided by changing its output format (see switch `/VALUE`)...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much aschipfl! 
The Scipt are working very good! I have add one more part about `cmdkey` to handle User/PWD if connecting to more than one Domain. Finaly here are my compl scipt:

```
@echo off
::# ------------------------------------------------------------------
::# specify Server Name (FQDN or IP Adresse)
::# IP: 10.0.0.1
::# FQDN: srv1.foo.bar
::# ------------------------------------------------------------------
set SERVER=10.0.0.1
::#
::# ------------------------------------------------------------------
::# delete old mappings for Server
::# ------------------------------------------------------------------
rem // Initialise index counter:
set /A "COUNT=0"
rem /* Capture output of the `wmic` command line that is filtered by a `where` clause;
rem    this returns only the drives, filtered for network drives (`DriveType=4`);
rem    two nested loops avoid text conversion artefacts like orphaned CR marks: */
for /F "delims=" %%K in ('
    wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=4 and ProviderName like '\\\\%SERVER%\\%%'" get DeviceID /VALUE
') do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("%%K") do (
    rem /* Capture output of the `wmic` command line that returns the mapping target
    rem    that corresponds with the current drive: */
    for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
        wmic LogicalDisk where "DeviceID='%%J'" get ProviderName /VALUE
    ') do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%E in ("%%G") do (
        rem // Increment index counter:
        set /A "COUNT+=1"
        rem // Revert handling of `&` by `wmic`, hence replace `&amp;` by `&`:
        set "NAME=%%F" & call set "NAME=%%NAME:&amp;=&%%"
        rem /* Store current mapping into array-like variable;
        rem    `call` and double-`%` in `%%COUNT%%` are necessary as `COUNT` is modified
        rem    and read within the same block of code (`%COUNT%` would return `0`): */
        call set "$MAP[%%COUNT%%]=%%J|%%NAME%%"
        rem // Delete the current mapping:
        net use %%J /DELETE
        cmdkey /delete:%SERVER%
    )
)
::#
::# ------------------------------------------------------------------
::# Get User Information
::# ------------------------------------------------------------------
set /p U-ID=Bitte U-ID eingeben: 
set /p Pwd=Bitte das NEU vergebene Passwort eingeben: 
::#
::# ------------------------------------------------------------------
::# New mappings for Server
::# ------------------------------------------------------------------
rem // Loop over all array elements:
for /F "tokens=1-2* delims=|=" %%H in ('2^> nul set $MAP[') do (
    rem // Establish remapping with new user data:
    cmdkey /add:%SERVER% /user:%U-ID%@foo.bar /pass:%PWD%
    net use %%I "%%J" /PERSISTENT:YES
    rem // Delete handled array element:
    set "%%H="
)
```

Offcourse the cmdkey runs serveral time but that is ok.
Thank you very much for helping!
Beste regrads AxelF